# How can I substitute single chars with empty string and double with single in Java using Regex?

Tags: regex

**Problem:**

I have to parse the CSV file, some lines are quoted.
I already split all columns correctly, and I need to remove single quotes and replace escaped quotes.

**Here some examples that I have to handle:**

```
["] -> []
[""] -> ["]
["""] -> ["]
[""""] -> [""]

["ab"c] -> [abc]
["Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large"""] -> [Venture "Extended Edition, Very Large"]
```

This is what I've got at the moment:

https://regex101.com/r/4uGEzN/1

I tried to write some regex with "Groups" and "Positive Lookahead" but didn't achieve the result. Can you help, please?

Comment: What do you want to do with `"a",""b"",""""c"""",""""`? It does not seem a valid string. What you maay do is match any `"...."` between commas using `(?m)(?<=,|^)"([^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*)"(?=$|,)` and then replace with a version with replaced (`.replace("\"\"", "\"")`) quotes inside the Group 1 value. It will work if the entries are valid CSV strings.

Comment: You can ignore commas, I need to transform string like this `"a" ""b"" """"c"""" """" """` into `a "b" ""c"" "" "`

Comment: Let's see as that all `"` are escaped

Comment: Well, that does not clear things out. Taking into account the title, I can suggest `.replaceAll("(?<!\")\"(?!\")|(\")\"", "$1")` (this is Java). See [this regex demo](https://regexr.com/4r624) (sorry, had to edit the link as regex101 was down)

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(")"|"
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L7cVXu/1/).

**Pattern details**

- `(")"` - captures a `"` into Group 1 and then just consumes another quote right after it
- `|` - or
- `"`  - matches  a single `"` char.

In Java, you may use this pattern with `.replaceAll`:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(\")\"|\"", "$1");
```

Comment: Strange behavior with `"\"Venture \"\"Extended Edition\"\"\""` something wrong with the last quote

Comment: @mkUltra Precise the requirements then. Examples are not quite helpful.

Comment: Every single quote folds into empty char, every double quote folds into a single. In the case of tree quotes first two should fold into one, e the last one disappear since single.

Comment: @mkUltra Try `.replaceAll("(\")\"|\"", "$1")`

Comment: Thank you for help. A combination of two works well: `(?<!\")\"(?!\")|(\")\"|\"`